# Putting image in DataTable and setting table as datasource to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I'm having problems with putting an image in a DataTable and setting this table as datasource to gridview, I've searched everywhere, but no I had no luck.
Here is the problem:

```
    private void populateGrid()
    {
       // Gets a datatable from a stored procedure
        DataTable ragTable = ProjetoBO.HistoricoRAGStatusProjeto(Convert.ToInt32(Session["idProjeto"]));

        int group= -1;

        int cont = 1;

        var table = GetDataTable(ragTable);

        DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();

        foreach (DataRow row in ragTable.Rows)
        {
            cont++;
            if (Convert.ToInt32(row[9]) != group)
            {
                cont = 1;
                group= Convert.ToInt32(row[9]);
                table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                dataRow = tabelaFinal.NewRow();
            }
            dataRow[0] = DateTime.Parse(row[2].ToString()).ToShortDateString();

            //putting some random image just for testing purpose
            dataRow[cont] = Properties.Resources.myIcon;

        }
        //my grid
        histRagStatus.DataSource = table ;
        histRagStatus.DataBind();
    }
    //Creates a dataTable with the columns I need
    private DataTable GetDataTable(DataTable ragTable)
    {
        var newTable= new DataTable();

        newTable.Columns.Add("Date");

        foreach (DataRow row in ragTable.Rows)
        {
            if (!newTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(column => column.ColumnName.Equals(row[6].ToString())))
            {
                var newColumn= new DataColumn(row[6].ToString());
                newTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);
            }
        }
        return newTable;
    }
```

I've been trying everything I can, creating a new column like var newColumn= new DataColumn(row[6].ToString(),typeof(Bitmap));  /  converting to an image and putting there  /  changing the datatype of the column before adding to the DataTable... But no luck... I just need the right way to get an image from Properties.Resources and putting it on a DataTable, that will bind to a grid and the image will appear on the gridview...

Any help is precious to me right now =D

Comment: How is the image data being sent?  a byte array?

Comment: It's being sent as a Bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a method for natively rendering image files (including BMP) in a GridView.

In your case, what I'd do is save that bitmap in a local file in the virtual directory.  Once you have the file name, you can bind that filename to an `ImageField` column in the GridView.

Comment: But all my columns are dynamically created, so my gridview doesn't have a columns tag to put image field, it's empty, like this <asp:GridView ID="histRagStatus" runat="server"> </asp:GridView>. I Add everything to the DataTable and then I just bind it to the grid... Is there a way to add a image field in the datatable?

Comment: Do you have a background in Windows development?  This is one of the cases where WinForms and WebForms differs.  You can only bind a GridView to image URLs, not the images themselves.

Comment: Well, i've tried putting the image url (that's a local url to a directory on my computer)in the datatable row too, but it makes the same effect, it puts the string url and no the image... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since it's a web site, the URL has to be somewhere in the virtual directory (the website's directory structure).  Usually it'll start with a tilde (like ~/images/image1.bmp).  Regardless, you'll need to either set one column for images in the GridView, or you'll have to dynamically add an asp:Image to each row that you bind.

Comment: Yeah, i used the virtual directory of the image "~/Content/img.jpg" but it got the string too. But here is the thing: I dont create columns in the grid, i just bind the datatable to the empty grid. Can I add an templateItem or Imagefield on the dataTable? I've tried something alike, but could manage to make it work

Comment: Only option to do it without creating an ImageField would be to handle the GV's OnRowDataBound event.  Inside that, find the URL, then dynamically generate an `Image`, set its URL, then add the generated image to the cell you want in e.Row.

Comment: I can't manage it to work, i did as you said, but it resulted in the same error.                                                                                                                          protected void histRagStatus_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in histRagStatus.Rows)
            {
                for(int i=1;i<row.Cells.Count;i++)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].Text = ResolveUrl("~/Content/verde.jpg");
                }
            }
        }

Comment: I worked! i've used the event you said and changed the text to "<asp:ListItem Selected='True'><div class='ragStatusIcon' style='background-color: green;' title='" +
                        Util.FormataStringTitleHtml("teste") + "'></div></asp:ListItem>"

Answer (score 0):

Storing the binary Bitmap in the DataTable only works in Windows Forms with the DataGridView Control. In ASP.NET DataGrid you must reference to a image URL. The simple way is enable in your DataGrid the Event RowDataBound.

Then wire up with code to your image location.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowWEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Setup in your image column index. By Example setting 0
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text=Server.HtmlDecode(@"<img src=""./Images/pdf.gif"" />");
    }
}
```